# How are analog thermocouple meters calibrated?

Tags: temperature, thermocouple, gauge

In most modern thermocouple measuring equipment, the input is high impedance and approximates a perfect voltmeter. This makes the thermocouple measurement easy because there is no current flowing through the system and you calculate it directly from a lookup table.

However, older analog gauges that used a coil to displace a needle have much lower impedances like 10-15 ohms. In this case, the resistance of the hookup wire and the thermocouple itself start to come into play since they make up a non-trivial percentage of the total voltage drop.

How were were these gauges calibrated? Did it have to be performed on the final installation or with a specific thermocouple/gauge pair?

Comment: AFAIR old Analog Gauges were something like 250mV full scale at 50uA or 25kohms/V

Answer (score 2):

The effect of the resistance was not so great in comparison to the accuracy.

They were calibrated for a specific source resistance such as 10\$\Omega\$, and you would typically find that number printed right on the pyrometer scale. That's not the resistance of the meter, which is much higher. For low temperature ovens and plastics, around 30-50mV full scale and maybe 50uA as Tony says, so in the 1K\$\Omega\$ range.

The actual original installation of those things in serious industrial applications with their vacuum tube amplifiers and such like is a bit before even my time (we ripped out and scrapped a lot of them to install solid-state replacements) but I assume they would specify the thermocouple construction and the extension wire (if any) gauge to approximate the required series resistance.

I might add that printing a custom nonlinear analog scale with the associated markings, even in small quantities, was feasible in those days.

Comment: The meter that I am trying to calibrate measures at 10 ohms across the inputs with no thermocouple attached.

Comment: I have not seen such a thing, perhaps you could add some photos to your question. The ancient wood-encased instrument (containing a galvanometer with an optical lever, Hg cells and an almost equally noxious cadmium-laden standard cell reference)  I used to calibrate thermocouple instruments as a young fellow had a way to add resistance in series with the calibrated output. Of course we can do a similar thing with more modern and probably less stable instrumentation.

Comment: P.S. those meter movements were made to be relatively sensitive compared to what would be ideal for mechanical robustness - we'd prefer something in the mA range for that- so they often had provisions for shorting or placing a resistance across the meter movement for the purposes of transportation. The resistance damped the motion of the movement by converting energy generated by the coil moving through the magnetic field of the movement into heat in the damping resistance(s). Perhaps there is such a short or link present in your unit?